# NLTK and language detection

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, detection

How do I detect what language a text is written in using NLTK?

The examples I've seen use `nltk.detect`, but when I've installed it on my mac, I cannot find this package.

Comment: The `langid` and `langdetect` libraries do the trick and are super easy to use: https://github.com/hb20007/hands-on-nltk-tutorial/blob/master/8-1-The-langdetect-and-langid-Libraries.ipynb

Comment: `langdetect` is not very reliable (e.g. check https://github.com/Mimino666/langdetect/issues/51 for instance) and `langid` choked on a test Japanese string when I tested it. YMMV. In 2019, if you are not tied to NLTK, I'd recommend you take a look at `cld2`, `cld3` or `fastText` instead.

Comment: Nicely summarized here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48436520/2063605

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Have you come across the following code snippet?

```
english_vocab = set(w.lower() for w in nltk.corpus.words.words())
text_vocab = set(w.lower() for w in text if w.lower().isalpha())
unusual = text_vocab.difference(english_vocab)
```

from http://groups.google.com/group/nltk-users/browse_thread/thread/a5f52af2cbc4cfeb?pli=1&safe=active

Or the following demo file?

https://web.archive.org/web/20120202055535/http://code.google.com/p/nltk/source/browse/trunk/nltk_contrib/nltk_contrib/misc/langid.py

Comment: PS, it still relied on nltk.detect, though. Any idea on how to install that on a Mac?

Comment: I don't believe detect is a native module for nltk.

Here's the code: http://docs.huihoo.com/nltk/0.9.5/api/nltk.detect-pysrc.html

You could probably download it and put it in your python library, which may be in:
/Library/Python/2.x/site-packages/nltk...

Comment: Check this out.. http://blog.alejandronolla.com/2013/05/15/detecting-text-language-with-python-and-nltk/

Comment: The requested URL /p/nltk/source/browse/trunk/nltk_contrib/nltk_contrib/misc/langid.py was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

Comment: This is such a good answer. The simplicity of checking if the words are in the vocab is an amazingly direct approach to this kind of task. Granted it doesn't give you the actual language or translate, but if you simply need to know if it's an outlier, this is brilliant.

Answer (score 31):

This library is not from NLTK either but certainly helps.

> $ sudo pip install langdetect

*Supported Python versions 2.6, 2.7, 3.x.*

```
>>> from langdetect import detect

>>> detect("War doesn't show who's right, just who's left.")
'en'
>>> detect("Ein, zwei, drei, vier")
'de'
```

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/langdetect?

P.S.: Don't expect this to work correctly always:

```
>>> detect("today is a good day")
'so'
>>> detect("today is a good day.")
'so'
>>> detect("la vita e bella!")
'it'
>>> detect("khoobi? khoshi?")
'so'
>>> detect("wow")
'pl'
>>> detect("what a day")
'en'
>>> detect("yay!")
'so'
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that it doesn't always work. `detect("You made it home!")` is giving me "fr". I'm wondering if there is anything better.

Comment: Here is another fun observation: It doesn't seem to give the same answer each time. `>>> detect_langs("Hello, I'm christiane amanpour.")
[it:0.8571401485770536, en:0.14285811674731527]
>>> detect_langs("Hello, I'm christiane amanpour.")
[it:0.8571403121803622, fr:0.14285888197332486] >>> detect_langs("Hello, I'm christiane amanpour.")
[it:0.999995562246093]`

Comment: langdetect works much better for longer strings where it can sample more n-grams ... for short strings of a few words, it's extremely unreliable.

Comment: @MarkCramer The algorithm is non-deterministic. If you want the same answer each time, set the seed: `import DetectorFactory DetectorFactory.seed = 0`

Comment: Quick to install, easy to use. Maybe not perfect but for my usage, it worked fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 20):

Although this is not in the NLTK, I have had great results with another Python-based library :

https://github.com/saffsd/langid.py

This is very simple to import and includes a large number of languages in its model.

Answer (score 11):

Super late but, you could use `textcat` classifier in `nltk`, [here](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.classify.html#nltk.classify.textcat.TextCat). This [paper](http://www.let.rug.nl/~vannoord/TextCat/textcat.pdf) discusses the algorithm.

It returns a country code in *ISO 639-3*, so I would use `pycountry` to get the  full name.

For example, load the libraries

```
import nltk
import pycountry
from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer
```

**Now let's look at two phrases, and `guess` their language:**

```
phrase_one = "good morning"
phrase_two = "goeie more"

tc = nltk.classify.textcat.TextCat() 
guess_one = tc.guess_language(phrase_one)
guess_two = tc.guess_language(phrase_two)

guess_one_name = pycountry.languages.get(alpha_3=guess_one).name
guess_two_name = pycountry.languages.get(alpha_3=guess_two).name
print(guess_one_name)
print(guess_two_name)

English
Afrikaans
```

You could then pass them into other `nltk` functions, for example:

```
stemmer = SnowballStemmer(guess_one_name.lower())
s1 = "walking"
print(stemmer.stem(s1))
walk
```

*Disclaimer obviously this will not always work, especially for sparse data*

Extreme example

```
guess_example = tc.guess_language("hello")
print(pycountry.languages.get(alpha_3=guess_example).name)
Konkani (individual language)
```

Answer (score 0):

polyglot.detect can detect the language:

```
from polyglot.detect import Detector

foreign = 'Este libro ha sido uno de los mejores libros que he leido.'
print(Detector(foreign).language)

name: Spanish     code: es       confidence:  98.0 read bytes:   865
```