# searching for language recognition library in Python or web service

Tags: python, web-services, nlp

Is there any tool that provides language recognition functionality?

Like if I input a sentence of English, it will suggest that the string *may* be English.

I think I need one of the following stuff.

1. Python language recognition library.
2. Web service that provides such functionality.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the [GuessLanguage](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/guess-language) module pretty extensively. It detects 100+ languages and works really well for LONG pieces of text. English is very good. Other languages I am not sure. If you want to process short sentences at a time or tweets it is pretty bad as it was designed for doing detection on full articles.

My company (social media analytics) is currently looking for a replacement package as well and are exploring [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/download) as an option.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/)? See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182268/nltk-and-language-detection) for further information.

There is also a [web service from xerox](http://open.xerox.com/Services/LanguageIdentifier/HowToUseTheApi) which claims to do what you want.