# Language detect

Tags: python

Does anyone has any experience how to determine the language of a text using python?
Is there an available module for this in python?

I've already tried the google app (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/detect), and it worked properly but I cannot use it for a long term for loads of text files.

Answer (score 3):

I've never tried this, but it appears you can do this with [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) (Natural Language Tookit). See this [blog post](http://misja.posterous.com/language-detection-with-python-nltk) for an example.

The answer to the following question might also be relevant: [NLTK and language detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182268/nltk-and-language-detection)

Answer (score 3):

There's official Python bindings for the [CLD3 neural network model](https://github.com/google/cld3), which is what Chrome uses for offline language detection.

```
sudo apt install -y protobuf-compiler
pip install gcld3
```

Like all Python code from Google that I've used, it's unpythonic and just generally sucks to use but at least it works well:

```
>>> import gcld3
>>> lang_identifier = gcld3.NNetLanguageIdentifier(0, 1000)
>>> lang_identifier.Find
lang_identifier.FindLanguage(           lang_identifier.FindTopNMostFreqLangs(  
>>> a = lang_identifier.FindLanguage("This is a test")
>>> a
<gcld3.pybind_ext.Result object at 0x7f606e0ec3b0>
>>> a.
a.is_reliable  a.language     a.probability  a.proportion   
>>> a.language
'en'
>>> a = lang_identifier.FindTopNMostFreqLangs("This piece of text is in English. Този текст е на Български.", 5)
>>> a
[<gcld3.pybind_ext.Result object at 0x7f606e0ec4b0>, <gcld3.pybind_ext.Result object at 0x7f606e0ec570>, <gcld3.pybind_ext.Result object at 0x7f606e0ec470>, <gcld3.pybind_ext.Result object at 0x7f606e0ec5b0>, <gcld3.pybind_ext.Result object at 0x7f606e0ec530>]
>>> [r.language for r in a]
['bg', 'en', 'und', 'und', 'und']
```

You can also try the unofficial Python bindings https://github.com/bsolomon1124/pycld3

Answer (score 0):

There is [Language Detection API](http://detectlanguage.com/) which you can use from Python as a web service. It accepts text through GET or POST and provides JSON output with scores.

Comment: This costs money and I'm like 33% sure that it's just re-selling Google Translate, judging from the fact that it also uses `iw` as the language code for Hebrew which has been officially deprecated since 1989.