# Stemming of the multilingual text corpus

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, text-processing, stemming

I have a text corpus with item descriptions in English, Russian and Polish.

This text corpus has 68K observations. Some of these observations are written in English, some in Russian, and some in Polish.

Could you tell me how ***properly*** and ***cost-efficiently*** implement a word stemming in this case? I can not use an English stemmer on Russian words and vice versa.

Unfortunately, I could not find a good language identifier. E.g. `langdetect` works too slow and often incorrectly. For example, I try to identify language of english word 'today':

```
detect("today") 
"so" 
# i.e Somali
```

So far my code implementation looks bad. I just use one stemmer on another:

```
import nltk
# polish stemmer
from pymorfologik import Morfologik

clean_items = []

# create stemmers

snowball_en = nltk.SnowballStemmer("english")
snowball_ru = nltk.SnowballStemmer("russian")
stemmer_pl = Morfologik()

# loop over each item; create an index i that goes from 0 to the length
# of the item list 

for i in range(0, num_items):
    # Call our function for each one, and add the result to the list of
    # clean items

    cleaned = items.iloc[i]

    # to word stem
    clean_items.append(snowball_ru.stem(stemmer_pl(snowball_en.stem(cleaned))))
```

Comment: How about detecting language from a sentence/token of the text first and then using the appropriate stemmer?

Comment: You can make a rough word-language classifier by exploiting character existence and/or frequencies, and phonotactics. You might even add a fourth class, which would contain words that can't be classified, and likely due to length would not even need to be (e.g. English article "a", Czech conjunction "a").

Comment: Or use a ready-made one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182268/nltk-and-language-detection

Comment: @grshankar, @Amadan, Unfortunately, I could not find a good language identifier. e.g.`langdetect` work too slow and  often incorrectly. e.g. I try to identify word 'today': `detect("today")` it prints me "so"  i.e Somali

Comment: @lemon I have used `langdetect` too. I agree it is slow, but gave good results for sentences (I did not use it on tokenized words). Have you given `langid` a try? I cannot guaranty the quality as I haven't used it myself but might be worth a shot

Comment: @grshankar, did you use it for whole sentences? In my case, in one sentence there can be both Russian and English words.

Comment: I havent use `langid`. Thank you for advise, I will try to use it!

Comment: That's part of the reason I suggested you make your own classifier. But even `langdetect` can be okay if you tweak it (because honestly the API is kind of a mess :P ). Why try to see if it's Somali if all you have is English, Russian and Czech? See [here](https://gist.github.com/amadanmath/77d9bae747268f97eab2e22e7cd0a364).

Comment: @Amadan, thank you for your response! You can place your decision in the answers to this question, so that I will accept it as an answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though API is not that great, you can make `langdetect` restrict itself only to languages that you are actually working with. For example:

```
from langdetect.detector_factory import DetectorFactory, PROFILES_DIRECTORY
import os

def get_factory_for(langs):
    df = DetectorFactory()
    profiles = []
    for lang in ['en', 'ru', 'pl']:
        with open(os.path.join(PROFILES_DIRECTORY, lang), 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            profiles.append(f.read())
    df.load_json_profile(profiles)

    def _detect_langs(text):
        d = df.create()
        d.append(text)
        return d.get_probabilities()

    def _detect(text):
        d = df.create()
        d.append(text)
        return d.detect()

    df.detect_langs = _detect_langs
    df.detect = _detect
    return df
```

While unrestricted `langdetect` seems to think `"today"` is Somali, if you only have English, Russian and Polish you can now do this:

```
df = get_factory_for(['en', 'ru', 'pl'])
df.detect('today')         # 'en'
df.detect_langs('today')   # [en:0.9999988994459187]
```

It will still miss a lot (`"snow"` is apparently Polish), but it will still drastically cut down on your error rate.