# Iterate Language detection code over every cell in CSV and print the result in next column

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a program that returns me the language after detection when my input is hardcoded.
I want the same results after iterating over my CSV cells and print the corresponding language in the next column.

I created a code that detects language when the input is hardcoded. I now have an excel sheet with some ID's and text in different languages. 
I want my program to read the excel cell by cell and print the result in neighbouring column

```
from textblob import TextBlob
import pycountry
b = TextBlob("Si esta yayo si esta yayo alla voy ")
iso_code = b.detect_language()  
# iso_code = "es"
language = pycountry.languages.get(alpha_2=iso_code)
print(language.name)
```

This is the Excel I want the program to iterate over

```
id  lyric language 
1   Hello how are you 
2   Wie geht es dir
3   cómo estás
4   நீங்கள் எப்படி இருக்கிறீர்கள்
5   Comment vas-tu
```

How can I remodify my code so that I get my expected results

Expected:

```
id  lyric language      Detected Language
1   Hello how are you         English
2   Wie geht es dir           German
3   cómo estás                Spanish
4   நீங்கள் எப்படி இருக்கிறீர்கள்     Tamil
5   Comment vas-tu            French
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show how you want the Excel to be read. Depends on the library, you may have different way to read the Excel. But let's say you use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from textblob import TextBlob
import pycountry

def country(textstring):
    b = TextBlob(textstring)
    iso_code = b.detect_language()  
    language = pycountry.languages.get(alpha_2=iso_code)
    return language.name

df = pd.read_excel("myexcel.xlsx")
df["Detected Language"] = df["lyric language"].apply(country)
print(df.to_string())
```

This approach use pandas' `Series.apply()` method to find the language of every cell in the column `lyric language`, and assign the result to a new column.

Comment: Thanks! This is great. Is it possible to write the new column and the data to the same excel sheet?

Comment: Again, *if you're using pandas*, simply `df.to_excel("myexcel.xlsx")`, but actually what it does is to overwrite your old sheet. Otherwise you need a different way to open existing and manupulate instead of overwrite.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your help

Comment: If I use this script for thousands of cell in excel, It gives me a error: http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
Is there any alternative to textblb.. I read that Google Translate service for textblob is no longer free. Also, since my IP is now blocked I cant run this program at all.Is there any solution for this

Comment: Not familiar with that. But see if this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182268/nltk-and-language-detection

Comment: I'm also seeing HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request with a file over 1k rows. Has anyone else encountered this or found a solution for it?